# JWT Bearer Token is being issued, but endpoint authentication fails

Tags: rest, .net-core, oauth, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

Code is .NET 8, using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer authentication.

This is my first time implementing JWT on my REST server, so I suspect it may be a newbie mistake.  Can you spot why this is occurring?

Symptom:  I perform my login function, it creates a Bearer ticket and returns it.  I then put the Bearer ticket in the data request endpoint, and it comes back with nothing (on CURL), or "Bearer error = invalid token" on SoapUI.

I have made sure that my Audience in the client request matches the one issued in the JWT ticket, and I am extremely careful to copy the Bearer token to include all characters and no extra.

If I remove the [Authorize] property on the Controller, calling the data request endpoint returns the data just great, so I know the method works.

When I integrated JWT with my REST server, I followed these steps:

1. Add integration to Program.cs

```
...
//=== OTB Template
builder.Services.AddControllers();

//=== Added for OAUTH / JWT
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidIssuer = ServerUtility.GetConfigValue("Jwt:Issuer"),
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ServerUtility.GetConfigValue("Jwt:Key"))),
    };
});

...
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

// Added for JWT
app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapControllers();
```

2. My Login function, in "TokenController.cs":

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostToken(UserModel APIUser)
        {
            try
            {
                if (APIUser is not null)
                {
                    var user = await GetUser(APIUser.apiUserId);
                    if (user is not null)
                    {
                        // Create a claim
                        var claims = new[]
                        {
                            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, ServerUtility.GetConfigValue("Jwt:Subject")),
                            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.apiUserName),
                            new Claim("UserId", user.apiUserId.ToString()),
                            new Claim("DisplayName", user.apiUserName),
                            new Claim("Email", $"{user.apiRecoveryEmail}"),
                        };
                        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ServerUtility.GetConfigValue("Jwt:Key")));
                        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                            ServerUtility.GetConfigValue("Jwt:Issuer"),
                            ServerUtility.GetConfigValue("Jwt:Audience"),
                            claims,
                            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                            signingCredentials: credentials);
                        return Ok(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound, new JsonObject() { ["code"] = 404, ["message"] = "Account not found" });
                    }
                }
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, new JsonObject() { ["code"] = 400, ["message"] = "Missing Account info in request" });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new JsonObject() { ["code"] = 500, ["message"] = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

3. My Data Request endpoint (different controller):

```
    [Route("/api/[Controller]"), ApiController, Authorize]
    public class AccountsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IAccount _IAccount;

        public AccountsController(IAccount IAccount)
        {
            _IAccount = IAccount;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AccountModel>>> GetAccountsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(_IAccount.GetAccountDetails());
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

4. My CURL requests (Windows):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"grant_type\":\"password\",\"apiUserId\":\"SystemAdministrator\",\"apiAPIKey\":\"the-appropriate-code\",\"apiAPISecret\":\"the-appropriate-code\",\"client_id\":\"GV_App\",\"client_secret\":\"your_client_secret\"}" https://localhost:7089/api/Token
```

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.-RwUCP6brplGbHIW2npmPOaWHPQ5GSV1dLudWTpgfT8" https://localhost:7089/api/Accounts
```

##UPDATE:  A few other things I have tried unsuccessfully, after another day of extensive web searches

1. Reordering the Program.cs app.{service}() (UseAuthentication, UseAuthorization, etc.)
2. Adding a bunch of options to my builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen()
3. Putting a simple Authorized endpoint in the same controller as my Token generator
4. Stripping down the Program.cs JWT options in builder.Services.AddAuthentication() to a bare minimum (turning off ValidateIssuer, ValidateAudience)

...and a few others that I cannot recall at the moment.  I have found a lot of people reporting that authorized endpoints always give error 401, but none of the solutions they provided have solved my issue.

Comment: FYI, if I paste the token into https://jwt.io, it shows the content, but at the bottom says "Invalid Signature."

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Michal Trojanowski, who correctly pointed out that `iat` format was the culprit.  According to my research, Microsoft introduced a breaking update to the processing of JWT datetime stamps.  Previously, it took the timestamps in a variety of formats and converted them - but that must have been considered some kind of security threat, and now it only takes it in numeric (int) format, which is UNIX Time based.  The culprit is on my token generation authentication endpoint, instead of using `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()`, which produces a value in the format of `2/29/2024 1:46:47 PM`, I should have used `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()`, which produces a value like `1709214494`.

VERY IMPORTANT NOTE:  Don't forget the parenthesis `()` indicating the Function call - leaving them out will not produce a compiler error if you use interpolated strings, but will give a result in the wrong format and not get the numeric result desired.

So, the working ticket issuance code now reads:

```
    // Create a claim
    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, ServerUtility.GetJSONValue(_cfgFile, "Jwt:Subject")),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, $"{Guid.NewGuid()}"),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, $"{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()}"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.apiUserName),
        new Claim("UserId", user.apiUserId.ToString()),
        new Claim("DisplayName", user.apiUserName),
        new Claim("Email", $"{user.apiRecoveryEmail}"),
    };
    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ServerUtility.GetJSONValue(_cfgFile, "Jwt:Key")));
    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        ServerUtility.GetJSONValue(_cfgFile, "Jwt:Issuer"),
        ServerUtility.GetJSONValue(_cfgFile, "Jwt:Audience"),
        claims,
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
        signingCredentials: credentials);
    return Ok(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));
```

Meanwhile, another VERY interesting line of research that led me to validate Michal's assertion that iat was the culprit, I discovered that you can assign code to authorization events when adding JWT Bearer authentication to your application Services.  Have a look at the code below - notice the `options.Events` portion.  To prove it, I set a breakpoint in the `OnAuthenticationFailed` event, and examined the contents of the `context` object.  This led me to the following inner error messages, which were obfuscated by higher level catches and throws.  The top level exception claimed that the ticket was malformed and needed to have portions separated by dots (.) - which was ridiculous, of course it had those.  I then looked at the InnerException, and had to drill down into various sublevels of InnerExceptions, but I found these 2 salient messages:

```
{"IDX14101: Unable to decode the payload '[PII of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.SecurityArtifact' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' as Base64Url encoded string."}
{"IDX11020: The JSON value of type: 'String', could not be converted to 'JsonTokenType.String'. Reading: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken.iat', Position: '82', CurrentDepth: '1', BytesConsumed: '105'."}
```

Note the failure of converting a string to a number - that was my clue that Michal was correct.

```
//=== Added for JWT
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents() 
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = ServerUtility.GetJSONValue(cfgFile, "Jwt:Issuer"),
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = ServerUtility.GetJSONValue(cfgFile, "Jwt:Audience"),
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ServerUtility.GetJSONValue(cfgFile, "Jwt:Key"))),
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls put `app.UseAuthorization();` behind `app.UseAuthentication();`.

I had a test with code below, it brings me 401 error while putting `UseAuthorization` behind `UseAuthentication` would return 200.

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
//app.UseAuthorization();
```

We [have document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#middleware-order) which mentioned

> UseCors, UseAuthentication, and UseAuthorization must appear in the
> order shown.

By the way, `Invalid Signature` should be the [expected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70538400).

In the end, we might test without validate Issuer and Audience temporarily just for test purpose. But I don't think your issue is caused by this. Your code worked well in my side, even if I set `ValidateIssuer = true,` and use a token which showing `Invalid Signature` when decode it in jwt.io

```
.AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
{
    cfg.SaveToken = true;
    cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidAudience = "Test.com",
        ValidIssuer = "Test.com",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is my custom Secret key for authentication"))
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for responding.  I am unclear what you mean by "behind" - but I moved .UseAuthorization to **after** .UseAuthentication, same behavior.  That link you found on MS website is very good.  Incidentally, I discovered jwt.io has a secret in the lower right corner that if you remove or change, it changes signature to valid.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response, since I'm not able to reproduce the issue with your code, so I'm afraid that there's something else affect the issue. By the way, I found [a test before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73683912/14574199) you might check it as well.

Comment: Yes, just look at the answer I posted - I found out that the iat date was formatted wrong, and ended up learning how to catch the inner exception during token authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the logs for any concrete errors? Maybe there is a clue as to what is wrong with the request.

When you create the token, you set the `iat` claim manually, but you set it to a string. This claim should have a numeric value of the timestamp. Do you have to set the claim manually? Isn't it added by the library? If not, then make sure that you're adding a numeric timestamp there, instead of a string (compare with the value of the `exp` claim). My guess is that the verification is failing because of that value.

As a side note, mind these few notes:

- You're actually not using OAuth, you're just using JWTs as access tokens. OAuth is a security framework with standards that describe how tokens are obtained from an authorization server. You're not implementing any of these flows. (If you thought of implementing the Resource Owner Password Credential flow, then please don't do that. It's a legacy flow that was added to OAuth only for simpler integration with solutions that existed before OAuth. The flow will soon be removed from the spec in OAuth 2.1)
- If I understand correctly, you have the same backend that is both issuing and verifying tokens. In that case, I think that using JWTs is an overkill. I think it will be simpler to go with plain old HTTP sessions and cookies instead.

Comment: I apologize for my lack of depth of understanding of the topic - I don't think cookies will suffice if the clients are not web browsers - our intended clients are other servers.  I understand now that it is not OAUTH but a simple bearer token provided by the authentication routine.  Yes, same backend, so why is the Authorize function not taking the token?

Comment: As to your other suggestion about `iat`, as you can see in the code it sets it to the DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() value - which is a string.  Are you suggesting to remove the ToString() method?  I got that from this example: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-implement-jwt-authentication-in-web-api-using-net-6-0-asp-net-core/

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "check the logs" - what logs?  Windows Event logs?

Comment: That's true, if it's not intended for browsers, then cookies are not a good option. By the way, shouldn't the `Authorize` annotation be a separate entry? `[Authorize]`

Comment: You can try if removing `toString()` from the UTcNow method works. I'm not that familiar with .NET unfortunately. Yet, your `iat` claim should look like the `exp` claim in the resulting token (and now you can see that they are different).

Comment: By logs, I mean your server logs. When you run your application (especially in development mode on your computer), it should be printing out some messages. If there are any issues with validating the token, the application should print out some log messages.

Comment: Michal, I like to gather my function attributes with commas, it's my style!  Of course, your hint about IAT turned out to be the key - but along the way, I found out some very interesting and useful things.  I am going to post my answer as a separate answer with code snippet because it is a bit lengthy, but definitely you were right about IAT, specifically because Microsoft introduced a breaking update after .NET 6, so older posts weren't updated and many weren't aware of it.

Comment: Ah, glad you found the the cause!